# Supress error messages when pasting into SQL / Vertica Terminal

Tags: command-line-interface, suppress-warnings, vertica

When I paste my SQL code into the Vertica Analytic Database interactive terminal, I receive this after each line of code:

```
owen(> 
ABORT           BEGIN           COPY            DROP            EXPLAIN       LOCK            RESET           SAMPLE STORAGE  SET             TRUNCATE        
ALTER           COMMENT         CREATE          END             GRANT           PREPARE         REVOKE          SAVEPOINT       SHOW            UPDATE          
ANALYZE         COMMIT          DELETE          EXECUTE         INSERT          RELEASE         ROLLBACK        SELECT          START           
owen(> 
ABORT           BEGIN           COPY            DROP            EXPLAIN         LOCK            RESET           SAMPLE STORAGE  SET             TRUNCATE        
ALTER           COMMENT         CREATE          END             GRANT           PREPARE         REVOKE          SAVEPOINT       SHOW            UPDATE          
ANALYZE         COMMIT          DELETE          EXECUTE         INSERT          RELEASE         ROLLBACK        SELECT          START           
 owen(> and source_ts >= extract(epoch from timestamp :start_date at timezone :timezone)
owen(> 
ABORT           BEGIN           COPY            DROP            EXPLAIN         LOCK            RESET           SAMPLE STORAGE  SET             TRUNCATE        
ALTER           COMMENT         CREATE          END             GRANT           PREPARE         REVOKE          SAVEPOINT       SHOW            UPDATE          
ANALYZE         COMMIT          DELETE          EXECUTE         INSERT          RELEASE         ROLLBACK        SELECT          START           
owen(> 
ABORT           BEGIN           COPY            DROP            EXPLAIN         LOCK            RESET           SAMPLE STORAGE  SET             TRUNCATE        
ALTER           COMMENT         CREATE          END             GRANT           PREPARE         REVOKE          SAVEPOINT       SHOW            UPDATE          
ANALYZE         COMMIT          DELETE          EXECUTE         INSERT          RELEASE         ROLLBACK        SELECT          START
```

I know this is related to the how the terminal processes newline characters. Is there a way to suppress this warning message?

Answer (score 1):

That's not an error message. This is because you have a horizontal tab (`\t` or `\09`) present when you paste. These tabs get interpreted and you get the auto-completed commands. You can either use the query buffer `\e` to paste & execute, or remove the <kbd>Tab</kbd>s from your code.